# Access Redux store from utility module

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

I am trying to export my store to a file, to configure *Axios* globally. Specifically, to inject a token from the store in the common authorization header. The app is running locally with *weback-dev-server*.

Here is the code for the app entry point:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { ConnectedRouter, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import Promise from 'redux-promise';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { logger } from 'redux-logger';
import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

import reducers from './reducers';
import Header from './components/Header.component';

const history = createHistory();
const middleware = [ Promise, ReduxThunk, logger ];
const store = createStore(
   reducers,
   undefined,
   compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware, routerMiddleware(history)))
);

export default store;

const App = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <div>
                <Header />
            </div>
        </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here is the file that configures Axios:

```
import axios from 'axios';

import store from '../src/main';

const select = state => state.auth.token;

const handleStoreChanges = () => {
const token = select(store.getState());
axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${ token }`;
};
 store.subscribe(handleStoreChanges);

const api = axios.create({
baseURL: process.env.ADMIN_BASE_URL
 });

export default api;
```

When I try to import `api`, I get the following error, because `store` is undefined -- leading me to believe that the import is resolved before it is instantiated maybe? --:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways of handling this, but a simple way is to inject your store using a function instead.

```
// axios file

import axios from 'axios';

const select = state => state.auth.token;

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.ADMIN_BASE_URL
});

export const injectStore = store => {
  store.subscribe(() => {
    const token = select(store.getState());
    axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${ token }`;
  })
}

export default api;

// store file

import { injectStore } from './api'

const store = createStore();

injectStore(store)
```

However, it makes more sense to me that the api file has no knowledge of the store, instead exports setters

```
// axios file

import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.ADMIN_BASE_URL
});

export const tokenSelector = state => state.auth.token;

export const setAuthHeader = token => {
  axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${ token }`;
}

export default api;

// store file

import { tokenSelector, setAuthHeader } from './api'

const store = createStore();

store.subscribe(() => {
  const token = tokenSelector(store.getState());
  setAuthHeader(token)
})
```